# Cannot drop column of existing table in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration, laravel-5.3

I am having a problem in Laravel 5.3.

It won't allow me to drop a column from an existing table. I have run 'composer require doctrine/dbal' and that worked fine, but my column will not delete.

My add_column_to_table code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddColumnToTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->string('avatar')->default('default.pngs');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function ($table)
        {
            $table->dropColumn('avatar');
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What error do you see

Comment: Try `removeColumn()` instead.

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference, but I don't think you generally use `Blueprint` when adding (or modifying) a column.

Comment: @user2693928 -- no error, the column just doesn't drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drop the column you need to rollback the migration in the following manner

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Comment: Ah yes, the problem I had was that I was just using 'php artisan migrate'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->dropColumn('avatar');
     });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rollback your migration:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

But make sure that column is empty on your table.